# typescript 2.0.x vs. 2.1.x, type definition filtered by switch/case statement

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

[@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) (an observable redux implementation for angular (2) ) uses this pattern to get the proper type to a reducer

[See the actual code](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/actions/book.ts#L34)

```
export const ActionTypes = {
  FOO:  type('foo'),
  BAR:  type('bar')
};

export class FooAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.FOO;

  constructor(public payload: string) { }
}

export class BarAction implements Action {
  type = ActionTypes.BAR;

  constructor(public payload: number) { }
}

export type Actions
  = Foo
  | Bar;
```

along with a reducer:

```
export class SomeReducerState {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

const initialState = {
  foo: undefined,
  bar: 0
};

export function someReducer(
  state: SomeReducerState = initialState,
  action: some.Actions
): SomeReducerState {

  switch (action.type) {
    case some.ActionTypes.FOO:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { foo: action.payload });
    case some.ActionTypes.BAR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { bar: action.payload });
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

The way it worked in typescript 2.0.x was that(I think) it would use the switch/case to decide/filter out what's the proper type for `action.payload`, so inside `case some.ActionTypes.FOO` `action.payload` was `string`, inside `BAR` it was `number`. Now with typescript 2.1.x it seems to be `any`. Is there any way to achieve the same results with 2.1.x? is that a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is by using `readonly` on `type`. Another benefit is that it won't require the `type` utility function to coerce the type of the strings anymore.

Full code [here](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/pull/88#issuecomment-272623083).